# MapBox SDK RouteLeg does not contain any information

Tags: android, mapbox

I am new to Android and MapBox so the solution might be obvious and I am just not seeing it.

I am attempting to implement a turn-by-turn direction type app for Android using MapBox. I have been able to figure out how to create a route, draw a polyline following the route, and have the user follow the polyline and reroute if the user goes off the polyline. But, for some reason when I try to get the next RouteStep from a RouteLeg of the Route, the RouteStep array comes up empty and I have no clue why this is happening. I have posted the section of my code that I am talking about below.

```
            currentRoute = response.body().getRoutes().get(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Distance: " + currentRoute.getDistance());
            Toast.makeText(
                    FollowRouteActivity.this,
                    "Route is " + currentRoute.getDistance() + " meters long.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            RouteLeg routeLeg = currentRoute.getLegs().get(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Next route leg distance: " + routeLeg.getDistance());
            if (routeLeg.getSteps().size() > 0)
                Log.d(TAG, "Next route step distance: " + routeLeg.getSteps().get(0).getDistance());
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "Next route step: No step found");

            drawRoute(currentRoute);
```

This code snippet always display "Next route step: No step found" to the log.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Also should mention that the currentRoute.getDistance() is returning the correct distance and the polyline is being drawn correctly when the currentRoute is passed to drawRoute()

Answer (score 1):

in your directions request, are you setting `setSteps()` to true? This should result in providing text instructions among other information.